# How are the letters "x", "w" and "y" pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

The letters "**x**", "**y**" and "**w**" do not exist in Esperanto. But when one has to pronounce them to spell names or other non-Esperanto things, how to do that?

La literoj "**x**", "**y**" kaj "**w**" ne ekzistas en Esperanto. Se oni bezonas ilin por literumi ne-Eajn aĵojn, kiel prononci ilin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fakte estas du demandoj: kiel *literumi* tiujn literojn kaj kiel *elparoli Esperantece* tiujn literojn.
PMEG respondas al ambaŭ demandoj. Mi provas sube resumi tiujn respondojn.

---

[Kiel literumi tiujn literojn](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/skribo/helposignoj.html#i-134) :

> - **Q q** : kuo
> - **X x** : ikso
> - **Y y** : ipsilono
> - **W w** : duobla vo, Ĝermana vo, vavo, vuo°

Ekzemple, oni literumas "exchange" tiel : e ikso co ho a no go e

Noto: "duobla vo" estas la plej ofta maniero elparoli "w". Ankaŭ "vavo" estas ofta. (www = vavovavovavo)

---

[Kiel elparoli Esperantece tiujn literojn](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/ne-esperantaj_vortoj.html#i-51p)

> - Q kiel “k”; QU kiel “kv”
> - W kiel “ŭ” (aŭ kiel “v”)
> - X kiel “ks”
> - Y kiel “j” (antaŭ aŭ post vokalo) aŭ kiel “i” (en aliaj okazoj)

Comment: Mi persone aldonus “aŭ *qu* kiel *kŭ*” por esti pli kohera kun la literumado kaj kun latinidaj lingvoj.

Answer (score 7):

Por "x", uzu 'ikso(n)', por "y" uzu 'ipsilono(n)'. Por "w" mi kutime uzas 'germana(n) vo(n)', sed mi konscias ke aliuloj uzas la formon 'duobla vo'.

Comment: Certe svedoj diras "duobla vo".